# Sophomore's Dream and an almost integer

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, power-series

It's related to the [Sophomore dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

> Prove that$$\int_0^{-\tan(\frac{59}5)}(x^x+x^{-x})\,\mathrm dx>2.$$

I can prove another bound easily:$$\int_0^1(x^x+x^{-x})\,\mathrm dx>2,$$which is true because $a+\frac{1}{a}\geq 2$ and $2×1=2$. Furthermore we have the two power series:
$$x^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x\ln(x))^n}{n!},\quad x^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(x\ln(x))^n}{n!},$$
so:
$$x^x+x^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2(x\ln(x))^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$
Then we have:
$$\int(x\ln(x))^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\frac{(n)_i}{(n+1)^i}(\ln(x))^{n-i},$$
where $(n)_i$ denotes the falling factorial. So with all this element I can prove the bound but it's not wise.

I would like to know if this could be done by hand as Bernoulli in this time. Any help is higly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why $\tan(59/5) $? Seems random

Comment: @YuriyS The smallest constant $c$ such that $\int_0^c (x^x + x^{-x})\mathrm{d} x \ge 2$ is approximately $-\tan(59/5)$.

Comment: @The.old.boy  Do you mean to calculate the integral by hand?

Comment: @The.old.boy If you don't really want $-\tan\frac{59}{5}$, it is more easy to prove $\int_0^{799/830}(x^x+x^{-x})\,\mathrm dx>2$ by hand where $799/830 < -\tan\frac{59}{5}$.